# Methods for storing and accessing hierarchical data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a terrain generator that has a lot of information about it.

Now look at this picture:

[image]

---

Also, suppose I have 2 functions:

1) `Function A` which takes as an input (x, y) coordinate of a tile, calculates biome and spits out a string of the calculated biome, for example `"forest"`.

2) `Function B` which takes as an input biome calculated by `function A` and returns string of the calculated element for that (x, y) tile. For example, assume it returned `"grass"`.

Now that I have those 2 pieces of information, I would love to *instantly* be able to access information for `"grass"` in `"forest"` in `"biomes"` just by knowing these 2 strings. Think of it like instantly accessing data from an array if you know the index of that information you need. For example, I would love to see which tiles can be placed on grass in forest biome (`string[] tiles` on the picture) and what is the probability for each of those tiles (`float[] probabilityOfTile`).

So, what is the approach here? How do I organize data to quickly access information based on strings that my functions returned? I was thinking about nested dictionaries, but the code gets really messy after a few layers of nesting, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be to use a kind of a "Composite key". So you can create the following dict:

`var dataStore = new Dictionary<string, CUSTOM_OBJECT>();`

and add keys which are a combination of strings i.e. "biomes_forrest_grass". That way you can get to an "unlimited" depth.
Usage:

```
var funcARes = funcA(param1);
var funcBRes = funcB(funcARes);
var yourObjectData = dictionary["${funcARes}_{funcBRes}"];
// then you can do it like this
yourObjectData.tiles[index] and yourObjectData.probability[index]`
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer I was looking for, but that is a really interesting idea nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: @FICHEKK Check my updated answer. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I understood what you meant ever before the updated answer, but as I said, I am not sure if this is the approach I am looking for (I was thinking maybe a database could solve this, but I am not experienced with databases so I don't know). However, thinking about this, sounds like it would do the job at the moment, so I guess this is the answer (at least for now). Thank you again!

Comment: @FICHEKK ah ok:) btw. the db approach would be more or less the same. you could just have an additional column (or computed column) that contains your key and filter data based on that